# Joomla Update: ERROR:AJAX Loading Error: Not Found

Tags: update, one-click-updates

I just had to update a customers Joomla site from 3.4.1 to 3.4.4 and when I click the Joomla Update button, it throws me a Javascript alert message:

> ERROR:AJAX Loading Error: Not Found site

Click ok on the prompt with the hope to continue the update, the updater stacks with the spinning wheel and nothing happens - no update progress.

I am unable to update - what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking for :

- Permissions and all seems to be okay.
- Php config settings (memory_limit, max_execution_time etc) all are set at adequate values, so they shouldn't be a problem.

This seemed to be a problem caused by the hosting provider's malware scanner. The restore.php script `('administrator/components/com_joomlaupdate/restore.php')` is missing and causing this error - also shown in the browser's console as:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
> (Not Found)

I know about this hosting provider malware that is deleting other essential files from Joomla core and extensions - I had faced similar  issues with K2, Akeeba BackUp and other extensions in the past.

So, doing a Google Search about this issue, it seems that other users in other hosting providers face similar issues, and they can't find what's wrong.

In such case - and after checking for the other common possible causes, like file permissions and php settings, the solution to update your Joomla, is to manually restore the Joomla Update component files that are missing and then do the update from the backend if in the meanwhile their scanner won't delete again your files.

The other solution would be to try to update by installing the appropriate update package through the extensions installer.

- As always, backup before performing any such actions.
- Re-think about your hosting provider - as it's unacceptable that they are deleting essential files from your site, without notifying you.

#### Ok a small update notice:

To not blame all hosting providers out there if it happens as such issue for you, in some cases, this can be happened by a prior corrupted installation of Joomla, or even manually if someone deletes this or other essential files.

Comment: Amazing how hosting providers are deleting Joomla core files. Do you have a few names of these hosts? Would be good to compile a list on Meta

Comment: @Lodder Well, not sure if this is the case for everyone that might have the exact same issue with the same cause - I would prefer not to mention publicly names here - but you could find some if you do a Google Search for this error. You will find some posts where they mention their providers. In my case this is a GR hosting provider and I have encounter similar issues in other sites in the past. But allow me to not name the provider here.

Comment: @Lodder, although I have no issue to tell you in private the Hosting Provide of the above case.

Comment: That would be highly appreciated as I know quite a few people who use Joomla outside of JSE. Email: lodder15@hotmail.co.uk